# asp.net mvc module wiseapproach or table wise approach

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

asp.net mvc module wise approach or different controller and repository for each table approach is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you elaborate on your question?  I think I understand... I like creating a repository for each table in a LINQ-to-SQL or entities model, for instance.  I think that helps group together related logic.

HTH.

Comment: well in traditional classes one is trying to bundle thing differently.like different table logic in different classes .
in controllers do we ought to bundle things up or make different controllers for different tables. what we should do?

Comment: In my app, MVC controllers are tied to functional logic, while the repository to get or modify the data is specific to a table.  That way, the repository groups the table-specific queries/modifications, but the controller may tie together multiple tables to display in the view... so that shouldn't be tied to a tabls, IMHO.